# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table ‘proposal_db.userlogs’ doesn’t exist

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I’m doing some customization inside the [CakeDC/users](https://github.com/CakeDC/users) plug-in. I created a table with name “user_logs” which consist of foreign key relationship with the actual “users” table provided by [CakeDC/users](https://github.com/CakeDC/users).

I baked the “user_logs” model using command:

> bin\cake bake model UserLogs --plugin CakeDC/Users

After user gets login I’m just generating log transaction inside the “user_logs” table. I added the following line inside the “/vendor/cakedc/users/src/Controller/Traits/LoginTrait.php” file under `_afterIdentifyUser` function:

> $this->activity_log(‘Login’, ‘Login’, $user[‘id’]);

And activity_log function is added inside the src/Controller/AppController.php file:

```
function activity_log($page, $action, $id=null){
$this->loadModel(‘CakeDC/Users.Userlogs’);
$dataUserLog = $this->Userlogs->newEntity();

    $dataUserLog['user_id'] = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id');
    if(!empty($id)){
        $dataUserLog['reference_id'] = $id;
    } else {
        $dataUserLog['reference_id'] = 0;
    }
    $dataUserLog['activity_timestamp'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $dataUserLog['page'] = $page;
    $dataUserLog['action'] = $action;

    $this->Userlogs->save($dataUserLog);
}
```

vendor/cakedc/users/src/Model/Entity/UserLog.php file code:

```
namespace CakeDC\Users\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class UserLog extends Entity
{
protected $_accessible = [
‘user_id’ => true,
‘reference_id’ => true,
‘activity_timestamp’ => true,
‘page’ => true,
‘action’ => true,
‘user’ => true
];
}
```

vendor/cakedc/users/src/Model/Table/UserLogsTable.php file code:

```
namespace CakeDC\Users\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UserLogsTable extends Table
{

public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('user_logs');
    $this->setDisplayField('id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'className' => 'CakeDC/Users.Users'
    ]);
}

public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmptyString('id', null, 'create');

    $validator
        ->dateTime('activity_timestamp')
        ->allowEmptyDateTime('activity_timestamp');

    $validator
        ->scalar('page')
        ->maxLength('page', 255)
        ->allowEmptyString('page');

    $validator
        ->scalar('action')
        ->maxLength('action', 255)
        ->allowEmptyString('action');

    return $validator;
}

public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['user_id'], 'Users'));

    return $rules;
}
}
```

**The surprise part is! this works on localhost but when I’m uploading code on a server it’s not working. On localhost I’ve PHP v7.3.4 and on server I’ve PHP v5.6.40. Can any one suggest what’s wrong with this why it’s working on localhost and not on server? Everything is same I’ve done almost everything cleared model cache on server as well but no luck. Please help.**

Not really sure why CAKEPHP is looking for table “proposal_db.userlogs” on server whereas I created “user_logs” table on both local and server. Please suggest?

Comment: Watch your spelling, `Userlogs != UserLogs`, the former will only work on case-insensitive filesystems, on other systems your class file will not be found, hence CakePHP will fall back to an auto-model, where `Userlogs` will be mapped to `userlogs` based on naming conventions. ps, do not create code in the vendors folder, you're going to lose everything when you're running a composer update.

Comment: Thanks, it worked I didn't noticed that type error.

Regarding creating code in the vendors folder, I removed the reference of "CakeDC/users" plug-in from both composer.json and composer.lock files.

I believe when I'll be running composer update it'll not overwrite anything with "CakeDC/users" plug-in. What are your thoughts on that?